# how to get event of change state of tabs or page

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, web-applications

I have one application who has two parts one is display module which is web based using `j2ee` and other is my backend service module which is on `java`. I have one page which has 4 tabs which has graphs. When click on tab, it sends start request to my backend application to start sending live data on my page. Problem is when I change the page to other page, my backend service keeps on sending the data. I want some way from which I can send stop request to my service program, when I change the page or close the browser. Please provide me some idea.

Comment: What you doing to start the sending? Which technology are you using for this?

Comment: i am using j2ee for my web app and socket programing for backend service program. when tab is clicked, i send request on port from where my service program recive the request.

Comment: That doesn't sound like standard web technology. But if you have a way to send close in your protocol, why don't you use it from the onUnload event handler?